# Laptop charging is not recognized by Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: power-management, laptop, 22.04, battery

After setting up my Asus laptop after Ubuntu installation; I noticed that in the top panel it is not showing laptop is getting charged! There is a notification LED on my laptop that will blink if I connect the charger. It is blinking. The battery percentage value in the top panel is not getting updated.
After restarting the machine while charging; the panel shows that it's getting charged. But even when I unplug, It shows as Charging.

I ran these commands after unplugging the charger.

```
[~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ACAD/online

1

[~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status

Charging
```

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: My UEFI is already on the latest version. I'm not able find a working solution.

Comment: In addition to any workaround that you discover, please file a proper bug report. Developers cannot fix it if nobody tells them about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with T480s. Ubuntu was seeing the battery at 47%, and it didn't go up or down with the USB-C power attached. When I removed the power, the battery % dropped to 46%, when I put it back in, it maintained at 46%.

Remove power plug from your laptop (USB-C) and power off the laptop

Boot the laptop and press ENTER on the Lenovo screen, then F1 key to access the BIOS

In the BIOS go to the Power menu, and turn off the battery. It will warn you the laptop will shutdown. Agree and the laptop will poweroff.

Put the USB-C power back into the laptop and power it on.

That did the trick for me

Comment: Some references please.